# Show OSD notifications without installing libnotify-bin

Tags: notifications, lubuntu, libnotify

I want to send my own notifications from the command line, that look like this:
[image]

I found out that it probably uses `xfce4-notifyd`.

I dont want to install `libnotify-bin` because when using `notify-send` the notifications look completely different (also its unnecessary to install another package when it already works, I just dont know how).

Comment: Suggestion: Post the screenshot of "notification look completely different" for comparison. I am sure that is just some misunderstanding of `notify-send` usage (I had used the command myself on Xfce, no such issue).